# Form validate() function not being called

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have created a form and I want my JavaScript to validate my form by checking whether the length of the persons name is `> 20`. If it is I am trying to make a popup alert appear but it is not working. It does nothing.

This is my HTML:

```
<form name = "enrol" onsubmit="validate()">
  <h3>Please complete the form below. Mandatory fields marked with *</h3>
  <fieldset>
    <h4>Personal Details</h4>
    <p>
      <label for="fname">*First Name</label> <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="lname">*Last Name</label> <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is my JavaScript they are connected through referencing. All other scripts work except function `validate ()`

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("The window has finished loading");
  var SubmitButton = document.getElementById("SubmitButton");
  SubmitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("SubmitButton").click();
  }, false);
  console.log("The submit button has been clicked");

  var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
  fname.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    console.log((fname).value);
  }, false);

  var lname = document.getElementById("lname");
  lname.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    console.log((lname).value);
  }, false);

  function validate(){
    var fname = document.enrol.fname.value;
    var lname=document.enrol.lname.value;
    if(fname.length>20){
      alert("Value can't exceed 20");
    }
    if(lname.length>20){
      alert("Value can't exceed 20");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Check the browser's console.

Comment: enrol is undefined in code, why are you creating loop of button clicking itself over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that `validate` function outside of `window.onload` event handler.

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log("The window has finished loading");


    var SubmitButton = document.getElementById("SubmitButton");
    SubmitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("SubmitButton").click();}, false);
    console.log("The submit button has been clicked");


    var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
    fname.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    console.log((fname).value);}, false);

    var lname = document.getElementById("lname");
    lname.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    console.log((lname).value);}, false);
}

function validate()
{

    var fname = document.enrol.fname.value;
    var lname=document.enrol.lname.value;

    if(fname.length>20)
    {
        alert("Value can't exceed 20");
    }
    if(lname.length>20)
    {
        alert("Value can't exceed 20");
    }
}
```

Comment: With this i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `validate()` function is not accessible in the *global scope*. The reason for this is because it is inside the anonymous function being assigned to `window.onload`, and thus is only valid to be called inside that function.

To fix it, just move it after the closing `}` for the `window.onload` function.

Comment: what about button that keeps clicking itself

Comment: That is due to the click handler added for the submit button that triggers a click on the button you just clicked. This is done in the `window.onload` function, but it is not what the OP asked about. They only asked why their `validate()` function was not being called.

Comment: while it's true that op hasn't asked for this, but it is all clear that it's a  bug or at least a bad attempt to accomplish whatever. Op infers that he doesn't know js that much so it should be natural to pinpoints any other flaws that are present in rest of js code...which is more logical thing to do.

Comment: A fix for the looping click button would also be appreciated - cheers.